# I am encoutering the following error: SSL protocol error-Failed to load resource while using socket.io

Tags: javascript, node.js, ssl, socket.io, backend

I am encountering SSL protocol error while using using socket.io using node.js

my frontend:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <!--include this script to integrate the socket server with the client server.-->
    <script src="http://localhost:8000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
    <title>Realtime Chat application like whatsapp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <nav>
        <img class="logo" src="logo.png" alt="image">
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="message right">Alice : Hey how are you</div>
        <div class="message left">Bob: I am fine</div>
    </div>
    <div class="send">
        <form action"#" id="send-container">
            <input type="text" name="messageInp" id="messageInp">
            <button class="btn" type="submit">Send</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="js/client.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

client server code:
```

```
var socket = io.connect('https://localhost:8000', {secure: true})

const form = document.getElementById('send-container');
const messageInput=document.getElementById('messageInp');
const messageContainer=document.querySelector('.container');

const nam=prompt('Enter your name to join: ');
socket.emit('new-user-joined',nam);
console.log(nam);
```

sender server code:

```
const io=require('socket.io')(8000);

const users = {};
console.log('run');
io.on('connection',(socket)=>{//A server which is connected with the various clients.
    socket.on('new-user-joined',(nam)=>{//Managing Each socket connection between clients and server.
        console.log("New user");
        users[socket.id]=nam;
        socket.broadcast.emit('user-joined',nam);//Broadcast to each client except the joinee that a new user is joined.
    });

    socket.on('send',(message)=>{
        socket.broadcast.emit('receive',{message:message,name:users[socket.id]});//If sender sends a message all the other clients should receive it.

    });
});
```

Comment: Your server has not implemented https, so you cannot use it. In fact, you are using `localhost:8000` with plain http in another part of your code (script src).